# Встретился забавный никнейм б/у-с (бывший в употреблении, сударь), - как единственно верно: словоер или?

Tags: лексика

...словоерс?

Грамота.ру, к сожалению, разрешает всё:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или я неправильно поняла ответ Справки?

Comment: Галина, если вас интересует вариант "словоерс" , в орфографическом словаре Лопатина на Грамоте это слово есть.

Comment: Меня "не так" интересует. Ответ Грамоты приводит все варианты с примерами из великих. Но даже у Ушакова, не говоря о совсем отдалённом Дале, есть только одна форма. Вопрос: почему?

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: Но даже у Ушакова... есть только одна форма._ === У Ушакова так: _**СЛОВОЕ́Р**, СЛОВОЕРИК, СЛОВОЕРС..._ См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1029462

Comment: Да, спасибо. Мне помнилось, что словарь после далевского; наверное, речь шла о Словаре русского языка Грота - Шахматова (1891— 1937)... в Гугл-Книге нашла и потеряла автора, увы. Но найду!

Comment: СЛОВОЕР. Обозначение несамостоятельного слова СЪ по названию в кириллице букв: С ("слово") и Ъ ("ер, ерик"). Употреблялось для выражения подобострастия, смирения, почтения к собеседнику: *Прошу-с! Благодарствуйте-с!* - Вот у нас слово и ер(ик), а откуда добавочное "с"? Утерянный автор объяснял...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вот у нас слово и ер(ик), **а откуда добавочное "с"?**

**Из старинной системы чтения по складам.**

См. [***Борис Успенский "Избранные труды"***](https://books.google.ru/books?id=4YAgAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA267&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%80%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO5Mqa28rKAhVDGCwKHUTcAJQQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%80%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

=============================================================

> *Как известно, обучение грамоте начиналось с чтения по складам, которое состояло в наименовании каждой буквы, составляющей
>   соответствующий слог ("склад"), с последующим затем произнесением
>   всего прочитанного сочетания…*

Т. е. ***-съ*** при обучении грамоте читалось так: ***слово-еръ — СЪ.***

Comment: Слава, это оно, моё утерянное, СПАСИБО! ))) Но у меня почему-то не было доступа к этой странице. А ссылка открывается на 267-й. Не могли бы Вы всю тему сюда загрузить - нет ведь в электронном виде!

Comment: Вот по этой ссылке - https://app.box.com/shared/5bnubd6pn7 - кажется, вся статья...

Comment: Можно и по этой: http://www.ruslang.ru/doc/voprosy/voprosy1970-5.pdf

Comment: Да, спасибо, она читабельнее.